# Broadcom BCM4360 - 5Ghz not connecting, but finding AP

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, broadcom

I had a lot of troubles for making my 5Ghz channel visible to my Broadcom BCM4360 (including reinstallation of the drivers). Now, I can see all 5Ghz wifi networks that works ONLY on low channels (I guess <100). However, I cannot connect to 5Ghz wifi network - even though it started authentication, completed it and then - no connection. Moreover, connecting to 2,4 GHz network is painful as I got very low speed internet connection here - maximum is about 3-5 mbps on speedtests, sometimes it is not even 1 mbps. I tried following steps:

- Reinstalling drivers
- Installing wicd (it is slower than network-manager though after installation)
- Blocking IPv6 (kind of, I used this):

  sudo vim /etc/gai.conf

and uncommented:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

iwlist output:

```
wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
      Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
      Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
      Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
      Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
      Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
      Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
      Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
      Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
      Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
      Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
      Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
      Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
      Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
      Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
      Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
      Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
      Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
      Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
      Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
      Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
      Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
      Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
      Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
      Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
      Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
      Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
      Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
      Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
      Channel 102 : 5.51 GHz
      Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
      Channel 106 : 5.53 GHz
      Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
      Current Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
```

My ifconfig:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"my_wifi_24"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: 04:92:26:3A:93:F8   
      Bit Rate=5.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Is there something I can do about it? I have also looked for dmesg, but the output shows my wlp3s0 card in IPv6:

```
[  797.133189] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  797.290173] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  834.797229] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  837.013071] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
```

Please note that I also have built-in network card wlp2s0 that appears in dmesg like that:

```
[  980.012074] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 04:92:26:3a:93:f8 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

My arch is x64,kernel 4.15.0-47-generic and I am using Xubuntu

```
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
```

Update: I have installed the correct driver from the driver table provided in the other topic about broadcom

Update 2: Adding output of commands:

```
 lspci -knn | grep -A4 -i "Network controller"
```

out:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

and:

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

out:

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 03
   serial: 50:3e:aa:d3:60:eb
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.62 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:f7400000-f7407fff memory:f7200000-f73fffff
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia why are you marking this as a duplicate? I have done everything mentioned in this topic and nothing works

Comment: The goal was to confirm the correct driver is installed.

Comment: Did you install `wicd`? So `wicd` is your backend now. Did you disable `network-manager`? Also post the output of commands `sudo lshw -class network` and `lspci -knn | grep -A4 -i "Network controller"`

Comment: @Marmayogi yep, network-manager is disabled (was, today I started it again). I will post the outpot in a while

Comment: @Marmayogi updated my question, I have also enabled ipv6 on my router today, I will inform if something went better